# set Django RawQuerySet to do not defer attributes

Tags: python, django

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#deferring-model-fields) if a field is trying to be reached in raw query set, it would fetch it in real time.

How can I prevent it from fetching fields not being retrieved from the database?

e.g. if I write `select name from authors`

and later a user will write author.gender it would return None and not attempt to retrieve it from the database?

Comment: Why do you want this behaviour? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it's a group by query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try fetching `null` for any fields that you do not want to be retrieved, for example:

```
Person.objects.raw('SELECT id, name, null AS gender from authors')
```

Comment: ye that works, but at this point, I know that I should just use a direct SQL query and not django raw objects. I used to work with HIibernate and the option of lazy loading or not was possible